# org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Connection from server1/xxx.xxx.x.xxx:7337 closed

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, shuffle, spark3

**Highlight**
I have upgraded Spark and trying to run already present Spark Streaming application (Accepts file names via stream, which are then read from HDFS, transformed using rdd and dataframes operations, finally analysed data set is persisted in to HBase) on YARN, which is failing and unable to solve the issue.

**Environment details are as below**

**Working with versions**

> *Platform 
> OS : RHEL 6.6, 128GB RAM, 42TB HDD, 32 Core 
> Java : 1.8.0_25 
>  Scala : 2.11 
> Hadoop : 2.7.7 
> Spark : 2.4.6 with Hadoop 2.7 binaries  
> HBase : 1.4.12*

**Not working after upgrade**

> *Spark : 3.0.0 with Hadoop 2.7 binaries*
>
> Compiled same code using Scala 2.12, as required for Spark 3.0.0, which had some minor changes as per version change, with no logical changes.

**Required YARN configurations**

> ```
> <property>
>   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
>   <value>mapreduce_shuffle,spark_shuffle</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
>   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class</name>
>   <value>org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>   <name>spark.shuffle.service.port</name>
>   <value>7337</value>
> </property>
> ```

**Spark Configuration passed while launching job**

```
spark.app.name=Ingestion
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.yarn.historyServer.address=${hadoopconf-yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:18088
spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs:///user/hduser/applicationHistory
spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
spark.driver.memory=1GB
spark.driver.cores=1
spark.executor.memory=5GB
spark.executor.cores=5
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2001
spark.logging.level=INFO
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.yarn.archive=hdfs:///spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7-jars.zip
spark.ui.killEnabled=false
spark.driver.memoryOverhead=512
spark.executor.memoryOverhead=1024
spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=4
spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval=1h
```

**Problem** 
The same piece of code is working with spark versions 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6 with same Hadoop,YARN,Spark configuration set.
As and when i am upgrading to spark 3.0.0, code starts to fails with below exception. Have tried multiple tuning like, increasing resources, decreasing partitions etc but no luck. Have checked for port 7337 via telnet, it is open and listening as well. After a week of debugging, was not able to find any solution to this and there seems no reason for shuffle port connection to be closed. 
*Working on data set which is hardly 50 MB. Same code was able to handle more than 300 MB of data having exact same configuration with Spark 2.4.x. This is weird!!*

**Exception**

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Connection from server1/xxx.xxx.x.xxx:7337 closed
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:748)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:663)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.processInputs(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.<init>(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2$adapted(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec$$Lambda$597/1323895653.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2(RDD.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$584/1207730390.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$421/1364680867.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection from server1/xxx.xxx.x.xxx:7337 closed
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelInactive(TransportResponseHandler.java:146)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelInactive(TransportChannelHandler.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:277)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelInactive(TransportFrameDecoder.java:225)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:818)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
```

*Did anyone else face this issue? if yes, please let me know how did you resolve it. I have no further clues on what more to check. Any help would be highly appreciated*
***Thank you***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark 3.x would not work with older shuffle service.

Try with following configuration change if you want to retain the older shuffle service.

```
spark.shuffle.useOldFetchProtocol=true
```

Reference https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29435